# How to print stack trace with line numbers in C++ and macOS

Tags: c++, stack-trace, boost-stacktrace

I want to produce stacktraces for certain errors. I tried Boost's stacktrace header, and I don't get line numbers. I'm compiling with the latest Clang. I'm using `-g` so it should be adding debug info.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// Don't know what this #define is doing, but it won't compile without it. :|
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

using std::cout; 

void foo(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
    } else {
        foo(n-1);
    }        
}

int main() {
    foo(3);
}
```

Here's the output. Nice, but missing line numbers.

```
 0# foo(int) in /Learning/Boost/boost_stacktrace
 1# foo(int) in /Learning/Boost/boost_stacktrace
 2# foo(int) in /Learning/Boost/boost_stacktrace
 3# foo(int) in /Learning/Boost/boost_stacktrace
 4# main in /Learning/Boost/boost_stacktrace
 5# start in /usr/lib/dyld
```

I also tried `backtrace`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <execinfo.h>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

void bar(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
         void* callstack[128];
         int i, frames = backtrace(callstack, 128);
         char** strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frames);
         for (i = 0; i < frames; ++i) {
             cout << strs[i] << endl;
         }
         free(strs);
    } else {
        bar(n-1);
    }
}

int main() {
    bar(3);
}
```

That output:

```
0   boost_stacktrace                    0x000000010a1840df _Z3bari + 287
1   boost_stacktrace                    0x000000010a184198 _Z3bari + 472
2   boost_stacktrace                    0x000000010a184198 _Z3bari + 472
3   boost_stacktrace                    0x000000010a184198 _Z3bari + 472
4   boost_stacktrace                    0x000000010a1842ec main + 28
5   dyld                                0x00007ff805a5941f start + 1903
```

Anyone know how to get line numbers?

I know that C++23 will have a [nice way to do this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace), but that is not ready yet in Clang and libc++. I have a very recent version compiled from source, from the git trunk.